# Are these hyperboles?

Tags: metaphors, literary-techniques, hyperbole

I have to write a diary entry in the perspective of Romeo about Juliet. We just finished act 1. so are any of these hyperboles ?

- When she walks outside, nature stops for a second to admire her beauty.
- She is perfect in every way.
- My love for Juliet is one that is impassable.

Comment: Given the definition of hyperbole, what questions do you have about its applicability in these instances?

Comment: This might be a better question to be posted on English Language Learners.  Otherwise, you should look up the definition of hyperbole and see if you can figure it out before posting on here.  I've given you an answer anyway because your question was polite, but many would vote to close this.

Comment: _Hyperboles_ (plural) sounds wrong to me. Isn't it an abstract mass noun?

Comment: See also [writers.se]

Answer (score 3):

Hyperboles are exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be take literally.

So, ask yourself this question:

Do these statements fit this criteria?

1. Do you think that nature *actually* stops to admire Juliet?
2. Do you think that she is perfect in *every* way?
3. Do you think that *no one could possibly* love anyone else more than he loves her?

Based upon these criteria, you should find that they are *all* examples of hyperbole.

Comment: While the first one is definitely hyperbole, Romeo may not see the other two as exaggeration at all. He is a teenager in love after all.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I agree with that.  But, there *could* be someone else who does.   Romeo likely does not have a register of *all* the loves in the world, and he cannot prove it. Hence it is likely hyperbole.  I admit I was on the fence on that one.

Comment: Agreed, objectively it's hyperbole. It's sort of like dramatic irony, where the audience knows it's a lie but the characters don't.

Comment: The OP seems to know what a hyperbole is. The question is if any of those statements are, some help in deciding. However, that is off-topic on ELU, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Kris See my comment above re: off-topic (the one close vote is mine BTW).  And, I did answer the question of *which* are hyperboles, I just did it by dint of the definition of the word.